# Trigger on Leads that checks to see if another Lead or Contact has the exact same name

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-management

I have created a trigger that checks to see if another Lead or Contact has 
the exact same name. How I can avoid the 
for loop inside for loop to compare old and new lead values and avoid 
running SOQL inside loop to get matching contacts? Code 
below:

```
trigger DuplicateLeadOrContact on Lead (before insert) {
    list<Lead> leadList = new list<Lead>();
    list<Contact> conList = new list<Contact>();
    leadList = [SELECT Id, firstname, lastname from LEAD];
    for(Lead myLead : Trigger.New){
        if(myLead.firstName != null && myLead.lastName != null){
            for(Lead oldLead : leadList){
                if(myLead.firstName == oldLead.firstname && myLead.lastName == 
           oldLead.lastName){
                    myLead.addError('Lead already Exists with same Lead first 
               name and last name');
                }

            }

        }
        conList = [SELECT Id, firstname, lastname from Contact where firstname 
        =:myLead.firstName AND lastName =:myLead.lastName];
        if(conList.size() > 0){
            myLead.addError('Lead already Exists with same Contact first name 
        and last name');
        }
       }


}
```

Comment: You can leverage duplicate management

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using trigger, you can leverage, out of box Duplicate Management functionality.

Refer, [Duplicate Management Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management)

[image: Duplicate Rule]